# How to handle nested html tables with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am loading an HTML file into a data frame using BeautifulSoup.  The table that I am parsing contains a nested table in every row, and I'm not sure how to handle this as it's giving me an AssertionError...trying to load 4 columns when there are only 3 columns in the data frame.

Here is the beginning of the html table showing the headers and the first row of data:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="99%" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12" id="tableid1">
         <colgroup span="3"></colgroup>
         <tr style="background-color: #CCDDFF;" class="header">
            <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left; padding: 0px; font-weight: bold; " width="33%">Bundle Name</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left; padding: 0px; font-weight: bold; " width="33%">Insulation Name / Layer / Layer PN</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left; padding: 0px; font-weight: bold; " width="33%">Bundle Width</td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="white-space: pre-wrap;background-color: #E4E4E4;">
            <td>BN100175-100861</td>
            <td>
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12">
                  <tr>
                     <td>B29* / 10 / POLYETHYLENE_CONDUIT</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td>25.53825</td>
         </tr>
```

Below is the code that I wrote to read the data into a dataframe:

```
    table = soup.find('table', id = 'tableid1')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

    allData=[]
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        allData.append(row)
     headers = allData.pop(0)
     self.d1_bundle_df = pd.DataFrame(allData, columns = headers)
```

When the above code is running, it generates the following error:
AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns

What's the best way to handle these nested tables?
This is still relatively new to me, so any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are searching in row for all `<td>`, but these `<td>` can contain other `<td>` in your case. One solution is use CSS selectors and search only for `<td>` which don't have other `<td>`:

```
data = '''<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="99%" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12" id="tableid1">
         <colgroup span="3"></colgroup>
         <tr style="background-color: #CCDDFF;" class="header">
            <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left; padding: 0px; font-weight: bold; " width="33%">Bundle Name</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left; padding: 0px; font-weight: bold; " width="33%">Insulation Name / Layer / Layer PN</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left; padding: 0px; font-weight: bold; " width="33%">Bundle Width</td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="white-space: pre-wrap;background-color: #E4E4E4;">
            <td>BN100175-100861</td>
            <td>
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12">
                  <tr>
                     <td>B29* / 10 / POLYETHYLENE_CONDUIT</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td>25.53825</td>
         </tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

rows = []
for tr in soup.select('#tableid1 > tr'):
    rows.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td:not(:has(td))')])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(rows)
```

Prints:

```
[['Bundle Name', 'Insulation Name / Layer / Layer PN', 'Bundle Width'],
 ['BN100175-100861', 'B29* / 10 / POLYETHYLENE_CONDUIT', '25.53825']]
```

The CSS selector `#tableid1 > tr` will search for all `<tr>` that are directly under the tag with `id=tableid1`

The CSS selector `td:not(:has(td))` will search for all `<td>` that don't contain other `<td>`.

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Andrej.  Would your code look different if you used html.parser rather than lxml?  I only ask as I have used html.parser in other portions of my code.

Comment: @JohnShambles In majority cases `html.parser` shouldn't be a problem. You could try it. For some complicated markup `lxml` is necessary though.

Comment: I tried your code, and am receiving an error:  NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: @JohnShambles You have old version of BeautifulSoup, I use version `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`

Comment: I got it to work.  Thank you very much for your help!